# TypeError usando Selenium con Python

Tags: python, selenium

Les comento, estuve haciendo un script de automatización en selenium para MercadoLibre, logre terminarlo y esta funcionando. El problema viene cuando quiero usar la librería unittest en el script. me lanza un TypeError. Acá les dejo el código y el error para que me entiendan mejor.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from ML_page import MercadoLibre_page
from publications_URL import publications





# email = input('--Email-- \n > ')
# print('-' * 30)
# password = input('--Password-- \n > ')


# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe')

# ML = MercadoLibre_page(driver)
# ML.login(email, password)

class MercadoLibre_page(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Userschromedriver.exe')



    def test_ML_publications(self):

        ML = MercadoLibre_page(self.driver)
        ML.login(email, password)
        
       
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\nTo start, we will need your credentials')

    email = input('--Email-- \n > ')
    print('-' * 30)
    password = input('--Password-- \n > ')

    unittest.main()
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: test_ML_publications (__main__.MercadoLibre_page)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ML_main.py", line 37, in test_ML_publications
    ML = MercadoLibre_page(self.driver)
  File "C:\Users\valen\.conda\envs\selenium\lib\unittest\case.py", line 433, in __init__
    testMethod = getattr(self, methodName)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Es raro, ya que como ven al principio, hay código comentado. probando de esa manera, es decir, sin usar unittest, el código se loguea sin problemas en Mercado Libre. Pero al usar unittest me da ese error.

Comment: Hola Valen. Creo que deberías informarte de como funcionan las clases y para que sirve unittest. Unittest sirve para hacer test unitarios, por lo que no influye (directamente) en la ejecución de tu código Selenium.

Comment: Por eso creo que es raro el error. Tal vez pase por alto algún error en el código pero no logre encontrarlo.  Pensé que era por unittest por esta parte del error:                                                                                                       File "C:\Users\valen\.conda\envs\selenium\lib\unittest\case.py", line 433, in __init__
    testMethod = getattr(self, methodName)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string